# Saving a plot using Hebrew (or UTF-8) encoding for text in pdf/svg devices in R?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, svg, hebrew

I would like to save a plot where the text (for example, in the title) is using Hebrew.  Trying the following won't work:

```
pdf("temp.pdf")
plot(1, main = "שלום")
dev.off()

svg("temp.svg")
plot(1, main = "שלום")
dev.off()
```

Although using:

```
png("temp.png")
plot(1, main = "שלום")
dev.off()
```

Will give the correct output.

Is there a way to fix it for pdf and svg as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about `svg`, but `?pdf` suggests you can define the encoding with more details in `?postcript`

Comment: Hi mnel - I can, but I don't see any option there that is "Hebrew" or "UTF-8"

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Cairo`:

```
library(Cairo)
CairoPDF("temp.pdf")
plot(1, main = "שלום")
dev.off()

CairoSVG("temp.svg")
plot(1, main = "שלום")
dev.off()
```

Comment: @TalGalili That's a shame, I have a feeling the solution might be system dependent then. What OS are you running?

Comment: I agree James.  I'm running win 7

Comment: I got it to work on XP/R 2.15.0/Cairo 1.5-1, so the available fonts should be similar. The only other thing I can suggest is to look at `names(pdfFonts())` to see what is available and try playing with the `family` parameter to `pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `pdfFonts` to assign a font that has the proper glyphs. At the moment you screen device appears to be using such a font but your pdfFonts are deficinet when it comes to Hebrew.

```
?pdfFonts
names(pdfFonts()
```

Comment: Hi DWin - could you please give another hint on how to use this for this purpose?  Thanks

Comment: I can illustrate it on a Mac. (But it's going to require some experimentation).  In fact I thought I already worked on a problem like this with you in the past? It might help if you offered candidate font names that you thought might have the proper glyphs. And it also might help if you said what was returned wne you executed the "hints".

Comment: Actually it's not as easy as switching fonts. The titles get handled by an .Internal call to title.